# how to create windows services by using python for openerp?

Tags: python, windows-services, odoo

I want to create a Windows service for open erp timesheet which will start automatically after user logged in windows system.

How to create service for above scenario in windows by using python which will support open erp v7?

Comment: None of 184 results returned when searching for [\[python\] \[windows\] +service](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+[windows]+%2Bservice) answers your question?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to create new service in windows I mentioned python because open erp development is in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried it but you can create windows service for openerp using "sc" command in cmd/powershell:

```
sc create openerpservice binpath= "C:\Program Files\OpenERP6.1\Server\service\OpenERPServerService.exe" \
type= own start= auto error= ignore DisplayName= OperERPNewService
```

You can start this service with several options

boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto(default = demand)

You can start/restart/stop this service using python code too as-

```
import win32serviceutil
serviceName = "openerpservice"
win32serviceutil.StartService(serviceName)
```